# Можно ли вытаскивать информацию из БД с помощью JavaScript вместо PHP

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JS, и многие говорят о возможности работать с БД через JavaScript вместо PHP. Говорят что это очень круто, так как времени на запрос будет уходить гораздо меньше и все происходит без перезагрузки страницы. Правда ли это так? И если да, то какие все же есть минусы в этом?

Answer (score 5):

Строго говоря, js может подключаться к БД. Например, если серверная часть на nodeJs. Тогда работа с базой будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'dbuser',
  password : 's3kreee7'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

Я понимаю, что, вероятно, автор вопроса имел в виду клиентский javaScript (хотя это не указанно в вопросе). Тогда ответ Evgeniy Zaritskiy вполне справедлив)

Comment: Да да я имел ввиду только через JS))Кстати если будет использоваться nodeJS в серверной части,то запрос данных будет происходить быстрее чем на php?

Comment: Есть много разных результатов бенчмарков с сравнением php и node, например http://www.hostingadvice.com/blog/comparing-node-js-vs-php-performance/  по моему внутреннему ощущению, лучше задуматься над структурой БД и оптимизировать именно ее для более быстрого отклика с результатами.

Answer (score 3):

*JS* не может напрямую подключаться к БД. Можно через аякс (*JS*): обращаться к *php* функции. При этом можно еще, например, посылать некие параметры (post, get). Подробнее здесь: [ajax](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)

Comment: Минусы это только в дополнительном определении самого аякса(больше кода)

Comment: Ну да я читал что это делается при помощи ajax, но скажите, сам факт  что времени на запрос будет уходить меньше, правда?Стоит ли так использовать JavaScript на практике?

Comment: времени будет уходить на обработку php столько же...а вот перезагрузки страницы при єтом не будет и потому такой подход делает сайт более динамичным, и быстрым, меньше дерганий в браузере для пользователя.

Comment: Боооольшое спасибо за просвещение)Теперь точно надо изучать досконально JS.

Comment: у вас буква "э" не работает?)

Comment: у меня установлено 6 языков, так что пардон)

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того, какого плана проект вы создаёте. Если сайт в основном использует операции ввода-вывода, то для него подойдёт Node.js. Если же требуется сайт, создающий большую нагрузку на процессор, то php по-прежнему нет равных.

Дополнительную информацию можно найти [тут](https://www.agicent.com/blog/node-js-vs-php/).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70436/discussion-between-qwertiy-and--).